# Could I "plug and play" a POST card?

Tags: bios, pci-express, post, pci

I have just one PCI POST card and a number of PC. I want to inspect booting process of each, in a manner, that if one is successfully booted (code 00 or code FF typically) - i need to eject POST card, plug it to next and boot it.

But i had an issue, where a GPU on mining burned out, when accidentely was partitially ejected from PCIe slot onder load, so i am kind of.. afraid and studied now.

So my question is - can i safely eject pci (and pci-e) post cards from running system?

And in a bonus addition, if you managed to know - can i plug in a card on a running system? Will that work, or current code just will not be detected?

Comment: Is it PCI or PCI-e? They're electrically very different.

Comment: @grawity my case is precisely PCI and hot-ejection possibility. But to roll a great and more informative answer you are welcome add information about PCIe cards, and hot-plug possibility as well. It's a total of 4 combinations of PCI/PCIe and plug/eject - and what could happen in each case?

Comment: Even if it is theoretically OK in a particular case, I wouldn't do it.  It's too easy to accidentally short things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle, both PCIe and PCI can do hotplug/hot-ejection.

Whether this works on a concrete system is a totally different question - the controller must support it, the connector must support it, and often the card needs to be specially designed with a few shorter traces on the connector.

So: unless you know for sure that all components of your system are specifically designed for hotplug/hot-eject, doing it is not safe. It might work a few times, and create a short circuit or funny electrical situation the next time, and kill some components on card or motherboard you still need.

Comment: Possibly worth noting that it's much more likely for any arbitrary combination of PCI-e card and host system to work correctly with hotplug than conventional PCI, given that PCI-e has had hotplug as part of the spec essentially since the beginning and therefore has a standard API/ABI/electronics for it, while conventional PCI got it retrofitted by multiple independent companies, resulting in at least 3-4 different API/ABI/electronics options for it.